# regex - two part number, not ending with dot or comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a help with simple regexp.
I want that only correct input is numbers max containint two parts and divided by comma or dot.

f.e

```
123 -> correct
123.123 -> correct
.123 -> not correct
123. -> not correct
.123.123 -> not correct
123.123.123 -> not correct
```

same for comma

I am using javascript for this.

Comment: You have tried anything in REGEX???

Comment: Try: `/^\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?$/`

Comment: This worked, thank you very much

Comment: You're not using jquery, jquery is (mostly) for DOM manipulation.  Updated tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can try as preceding. And you can learn some Regex basics [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

```js
var myReg = /^\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?$/;
console.log(myReg.exec("123"));
console.log(myReg.exec("123.123"));
console.log(myReg.exec(".123"));
console.log(myReg.exec("123."));
console.log(myReg.exec(".123.123"));
console.log(myReg.exec(".123.123.123"));
```